# Why is the word wrap (QTableWidget, PYQT5) painted differently when running .py from cmd than running with anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, cmd, pyqt5, word-wrap, qtablewidget

I wrote a GUI in pyqt5 where you can enter two paths (file paths, directory paths, ...). Now my problem is the following:

(1) when I run it with the Anaconda Prompt window, and enter any longer path then it does the word wrap how I want it (and afai can tell correctly):

[image: correct word wrap]

in this case using `setTextElideMode` works as well.

(2) when I run it with the windows command prompt (`C:\[...]\Desktop>C:\[...]\python\3.8.1.0.0\python-3.8.1.amd64\python.exe C:\[...]\Desktop\cmd_problems.py`) it begins wrapping the text directly after "`C:`" by inserting the normal ellipsis "`...`" - I have to stretch the column (manually) until the whole path is visible to make it show more than that:

[image: incorrect word wrap]

using `setTextElideMode` does nothing.

**Does anyone know how to get the first behavior when running the code from the windows cmd line?** (I need this because I use a batch script to launch the program similar to making an .exe file.)

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QVBoxLayout

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Very Important Window")
        cen = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setCentralWidget(cen)
        cen.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        self.tbl = QTableWidget()
        self.tbl.setRowCount(1)
        self.tbl.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tbl.setTextElideMode(Qt.ElideRight)
        col_names = ["FROM", "TO"]
        self.tbl.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(col_names)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tbl)
        
def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: what do you get when you run: `print(QApplication.style(),metaObject().className())`? in both cases

Comment: In both bases I get `QWindowsVistaStyle`.